# calling post.title in application.html.erb generates error undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have sidebar in application.html.erb.

```
<div class="well sidebar-nav">
        <h3>Rewards</h3>
        <% @rewards.each do |reward| %>
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
          <li class="nav-header"><%= reward.title %></li>
          <li><%= reward.price %></li>
          <li><%= reward.image_url %></li>
          <li><%= reward.details %></li>
          <li><%= reward.estimated_delivery %></li>
          <li><%= reward.claimed %></li>
        </ul>
        <% end %>
      </div><!--/.well -->
```

I generated Rewards by: rails g scafford Rewards ....following properties.

My rewards view is working fine. but when i going on other page i get this error

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

I know this is because my `application.html.erb` is looking for `@rewards` in applicationcontroller and it's not there. But i dont know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have it application-wide, you should set it in `before_filter` of `application_controller`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_rewards
  # ...
  private

  def set_rewards
    @rewards = #set your rewards here
  end
end
```